# Existence of homotopy operator is equivalent to zero homology

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra, differential-algebra

Let $(E,\partial)$ be a differential space. A linear map $h:E\to E$ is a homotopy operator if $h\partial+\partial h = {\rm Id}$.

Then, there is a homotopy operator in $E$ if and only if $H(E)=0$.

Checking that such an $h$ forces $H(E)=0$ isn't hard, but I'm having trouble constructing $h$ if $H(E)=0$. I'm happy with hints, since I'm doing this just for fun. This is an exercise in Greub's Linear Algebra book (I don't recall which exercise exactly, but the book is awesome!).

Comment: By differential space you mean a chain complex, a dg-algebra or maybe even other object?

Comment: It's a pair $(E,\partial)$ where $E$ is a vector space and $\partial$ is a linear operator in $E$ such that $\partial^2=0$. Greub does it like this "in the large" and then considers $\Bbb N $-graded spaces.

Comment: I know how to do this using an inner product and $\partial^*$. Pick $\Delta = \partial \partial^* + \partial^* \partial$ and $h = \Delta^{-1}\partial^*$. This actually works for a complex of vector bundles. This means that quasi-isomorphism and homotopy equ. are the same for complexes of vector bundles.

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind to use $\partial^\ast$. I'll try to use this, thanks

Comment: By the way, this result is not true when your $E$ is over a general ring and not over a field.

Comment: Figures... Modules just don't know how to behave properly :P

Comment: For sake of completeness regarding my last comment. Some criteria to the equivalence are in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59390/when-is-a-quasi-isomorphism-necessarily-a-homotopy-equivalence

Comment: I made the computation to make sure. $\Delta$ is an iso iff the (co)homology equals zero and $\partial$ commutes with $\Delta$, so it commutes with its inverse. The first part is essentially a finite dimensional version of Hodge decomposition into Harmonic forms $E = \partial E \oplus \partial^* E \oplus H (E)$ (see for instance http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ruiloja/Math519/romney.pdf )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, one way is trivial. For the other, split $E=E' \oplus F$, where $E'=\ker \partial= \text{Im}~ \partial$ and $F$ is some subspace (you use the fact that we are dealing with vector spaces here). Then define

$$h(e'+f)=\partial|_{F}^{-1}e'.$$

Since $\partial|_{F}: F \to E'$ is a bijection (why?), $h$ is well-defined. Note now that
$$\partial h (e'+f)+h \partial(e'+f)=\partial(\partial|_{F}^{-1} e')+h(\partial f)=e'+f.$$

OBS: *Caveat lector*. You have a very particular chain complex here (a "constant" one), but a chain homotopy raises degree in general. Be careful not to be confused with this (and **a lot** of quite particular instances in this exercise) in the future when you encounter actual chain complexes in homology.